# how to play GStreamer media on Flutter

Tags: flutter, gstreamer, flutter-dependencies, gstreamer-1.0, java-gstreamer

I want to know how can I get GStreamer to work on Flutter application to show a video on media player.
Any help and tips would be appriciated

Comment: Recently I managed to get the gstreamer working on flutter for both android and iOS. For Android do not use flutter 2.x. The rendering just not shows due to some issues. Wasted a complete week. Try 3..0.0 . Its working

Comment: @cdesh do you have a repo for this work? I am struggling with this as welll

Comment: There is now https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gstreamer_player

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need GStreamer on the device to play the video?
The main point is the source of the video - you can play:

- video file (https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)
- WebRTC stream (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc)
- HLS stream (https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web_hls)

without GStreamer at all.

Answer (score 0):

If need gstreamer just use platformviews to embed and do the rendering using native android and ios. worked for me.